# Ending a sentence with: "within context"

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Basically, does "within context" need a description of what is meant by that context, or is it sufficient to just say within context.

For example, when talking about information can you say: "This chapter gives a description of the data within context."

I found many examples of this use online but I'm not sure if it is correct.

I suppose what I am asking is does the above mean the same as: "This chapter gives a description of the data within the context it was created in."

Comment: It depends on (pun intended) the context. If the prior text has established a context, "_within context._" can be used, for example, at the end of a sentence to warn against generalising beyond the context [already described]. If the context isn't clear (from the context :-) ) then it would be better to explicitly state it.

Comment: I would use "in context" rather than "within context."  "In context" means exactly what you wrote in your last paragraph. // "The information is looked at within context" doesn't work as well as your other idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your audience but generally you should not assume that the reader knows what you are talking about. 
It would be much safer to add a short description such as "within the context of his/her research on ..."

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question is very clear. I don't want to elaborate on the context. I merely want to communicate that the data is not looked at in isolation but that the context of the data (the environment it was generated in) is also taken into account. And for that I am not sure whether saying e.g. "The information is looked at within context." is a complete sentence or whether it is as grammatically incorrect as saying "The information is looked at from a perspective." (which perspective?)

Comment: Using "within context" is allowed at the end of a sentence, but I do not think that it can be used in your example. It is far too vague to know what you are talking about.